# Sponsoring a community member to attend the 2011 RallyOn Conference

Tags: discussion, conferences

The [2011 RallyOn Agile Conference](http://www.rallydev.com/events/rallyon2011) is coming up May 10th and 11th in Boulder, CO.  We're partnering with Rally on this great (and invite only) event and as part of that, want to sponsor one member from the Programmers.SE community.

We're looking for a community member who can go to the conference (the whole time) to represent Programmers.SE.  You'll need to:

- Promote the community
- Answer questions from other attendees
- Help the audience make use of Stack Exchange throughout the conference

We'll also be putting you in touch with the conference organizers so you can coordinate your efforts with them (since they are asking us to send folks to help with these things).

If you're interested, let know (just submit your name and why you should go as an answer to this question).  If you can't go (or think that someone else would make a great ambassador) go ahead and vote them up.

The ideal ambassador should have a strong history on Programmers.SE and be a prominent member of the community.

Answer (score 9):

I'll throw my name into the hat.

Pros:

- I've been around on Programmers since the public beta and am still active. I'm a moderator, so I'm well-versed in Programmers.SE and Stack Exchange mechanics in general.
- I can put coherent sentences together on demand.
- I use Rally at work and am familiar with its feature set and general philosophy.
- I drink the agile kool-aid.

Cons:

- Like Jonathan, I'm fairly young, with only four years of professional experience.
- I live in Canada, so travel logistics are a bit more complicated than they would be for an American.

Comment: +1. Canada is better then international.

Comment: @JoshK Hey, we haven't been annexed yet... ;)

Comment: Considering we're broke I don't think that's going to happen anytime soon. O.o

Comment: @Josh: but Canada has *oil* - they just need to get all the sand out of it...

Comment: @Mr.CRT: True enough.

Answer (score 3):

Why I should be considered:

- **I'm sociable and energetic** - Conferences are all about networking and meeting people. I'm sure only < 5% is retained from everyone's presentations - I understand and am enticed by the countless opportunities to meet people at a gathering of similar interests like a fat kid at a buffet.
- **I give presentations at work** - I'm sure most people do as well. My line of work is scientific computing in astrophysics (funded by the Australian government). Over the last four years, I've given presentations which have had a wide variety of conference participants. I *know* how to tailor my behaviour and presentation(s) to connect with everyone.

Why I should *not* be considered:

- **I have an Australian accent** - While travelling along the west coast, I've had a mound of trouble obtaining *a fork* in the smaller towns.
- **I'm young** - I only have four years professional experience under my belt. My technical skills are notable, but they have a *long* way to go.
- **I'm far away** - This wouldn't be a 2-hour flight into a different state for me, thus making it harder to organise and more expensive.

Comment: Thanks for pointing my name. I would love to go to that conference but I won't be able to travel to US at that date. That said, I would be more than happy to help P.SE in conferences located in Europe. In fact, I'll be at Microsoft Tech Days next week and would be more than happy to meet anyone from P.SE. The least I can do it putting a StackOverflow or P.SE tshirt if someone can send it to me.

Comment: Hey Jonathan - thanks for the great analysis and offering up all the names.  this really helps!

Comment: Other nominations split into separate CW questions. Feel free to edit in other great things about nominations.

Answer (score 1):

#### [Pierre 303](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/2567/pierre-303)

> This guy *understands* people and shows it by knowing how to write. His questions are back with a lot of common sense but also include another point which people would never think of.
>   Jonathan Khoo

<sup>Proposed by [Jonathan Khoo](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1461/sponsoring-a-community-member-to-attend-the-2011-rallyon-conference/1462#1462)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

#### [S.Lott](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/5834/s-lott)

> A very knowledgeable member of the community. Even though he's the bluntest member of P.SE and would probably tell everyone at the conference to shut up, it's obvious that he's patient and would be able to connect with a lot of people.
>   Jonathan Khoo

<sup>Proposed by [Jonathan Khoo](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1461/sponsoring-a-community-member-to-attend-the-2011-rallyon-conference/1462#1462)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Why I should be considered:

1. My team uses Rally, and my manager is one of those invited. We've also been used in an article written by someone at Rally.
2. I'm sociable, have a passion for software engineering, and have no problem communicating ideas to others

Reasons I should not be considered:

1. I've only been on P.SE for about a month, so while the 1st and 3rd actions I'm comfortable with, the 2nd, answering questions, I probably can't answer some as well as someone who's been here for longer.

Answer (score 0):

#### **[Developer Art](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/8685/developer-art)**

> I'm continuously amazed by his input - some of the contributions made are astounding.
>   - Jonathan Khoo

<sup>Proposed by [Jonathan Khoo](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1461/sponsoring-a-community-member-to-attend-the-2011-rallyon-conference/1462#1462)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

#### [Berin Loritsch](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/6509/berin-loritsch)

> The same reasons as S.Lott, except he wouldn't tell everyone to shut up.
>   Jonathan Khoo

<sup>Proposed by [Jonathan Khoo](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1461/sponsoring-a-community-member-to-attend-the-2011-rallyon-conference/1462#1462)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Cross-posting on behalf of [Eric Willeke](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/users/21994/eric-willeke) from Rally Software.

Original post is [here on Meta.PM.SE](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/205/sponsoring-a-community-member-to-attend-the-2011-rallyon-conference/209#209).

---

A request from Rally, and some background on how we see our event interacting with PMSE.

#### Our Requests

First, I'd like the community's perspective on us adding a tag "RallyOn11" to PMSE that our attendees can use to easily identify and browse topics arising from the conference. After some period (90 days? 180 days?) we'd be happy to delete the tag as it would no longer contribute to the meaningful taxonomy of the content.

Second, I suspect (hope!) we'll be driving an influx of new members during that period, who will all be practicing members of project leadership. I know you'll continue as a group to be your awesome, supportive selves, and I wanted you to know we at Rally strongly appreciate the PMSE community.

I've attached a draft of what we've shared internally about PMSE for you to see in addition to what @Alex shared above.

#### Here’s our thinking...

The customers attending RallyOn are among our most energetic agile champions, and the questions they are willing to voice will be ones held in silence by many others. Equally valuable, posting the questions in an open, online forum allows our many users that are not attending RallyOn to share in and contribute to the experience by providing their perspectives and knowledge. We desire that the important and interesting questions raised by our attendees live on as questions in Stack Exchange, and for our entire team to provide answers, seeding the community in both directions.

The leadership of Stack Exchange is providing support by sending two community champions to join RallyOn and guide us as we try and share the knowledge we are creating during the conference. As such, please welcome Anna Lear (@aalear) and TBD (@TBD) to RallyOn!

We will rely on our participants in the roles of scribes, room facilitators, speakers, and members of the audience to keep an ear open for interesting and appropriate questions during the sessions. We need to help these questions find their way on to the appropriate Stack Exchange, likely either https://pm.stackexchange.com/ or https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/. It’s our responsibility to ensure that attendees have as little friction as possible in the process. However, it is very important that we strive to help our customers join the site rather than posting the questions ourselves.

Comment: I'm personally in support of the RallyOn11 tag for the duration of the conference (and some time after?). It would allow conference attendees to find ongoing questions easier and also allow those not at the conference to easily participate as well.

Comment: The tag requirement is onerous. 1. We're not Twitter. Tagging based on event is meaningless and detrimental to otherwise organic tag usage. 2. The point of Stack Exchange sites is to have a place for everyone of a single domain (i.e. Programmers), not to provide free question hosting for specific companies with no understanding of the dynamics of the site (the recent example of Synergy using the synergy tag as the primary support forum on SU comes to mind). Is there any reason they have to resort to artificial tag mandates instead of normal advertising?

Comment: @MarkTrapp I see this as a somewhat new (and controlled) experiment. The goal isn't to host questions on Rally's behalf, but rather to extend the reach of a small conference beyond just the people attending it and promote SE while doing so. RSS support for tags theoretically makes it easier for people not at the event to follow questions that come out of it. (With the understanding that the questions are on-topic and fitting in the first place. That's where I and a mod from PM.SE come in.) Once the tag outlives its usefulness for that purpose, it can (and should) be removed.