# What do you want to see from SCNA?

Tags: discussion, conferences

Last month Stack Exchange has [graciously agreed to sponsor me](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2314/software-craftsmanship-north-america-2011-sponsorship-proposal) to attend the [Software Craftsmanship North America](http://scna.softwarecraftsmanship.com) conference in Chicago next month.

The [conference schedule](http://scna.softwarecraftsmanship.org/schedule) is now up on their site, although the [speaker list and talk abstracts](http://scna.softwarecraftsmanship.org/speakers/) are still being fleshed out.

Since the main purpose of this trip is to bring information and knowledge back to the community here, what do *you* want to see? Which sessions do you want to hear about the most?

I'll try to make up a schedule for myself that hits as much of what you guys pick here as possible. And of course, if anyone else is going to be attending, come find me and say hi. I'll likely have stickers and such and who doesn't love stickers?

Comment: Mean people.  Mean people don't like stickers. ):

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff Well, I'm gonna give them stickers anyway and THEY ARE GONNA LIKE IT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things:

Notes and stories. Since the blog effort has been less than spectacular, perhaps asking and self-answering questions based on what the speakers say, or finding questions on here about things that the speakers are talking about and answering with their advice. Somehow getting things out of this conference to all of us who can't go. Personally, I would be interested in what Stephen Anderson, Fred George, Uncle Bob, Todd Sedano, and Zed Shaw (I love his methodology, btw) have to say.

Users. Sell Programmers, get more people to ask and answer awesome questions.